# Add label to right of toggle button

Tags: html, css, toggle

I would like to know how can I add the label to the right side of the below toggle.

I tried to add label which is not correctly aligned.

Any help is apprecitated.

Plunkr   link - https://plnkr.co/edit/NdnF2OycDZpk2FiiB7D6?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 20px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have an answer but it uses display: flex, do you need an answer for old browsers or would that be enough?

Comment: Hope this will help you. Please check link https://fiddle.jshell.net/h1vuuz2t/

Comment: Add css on this class:  .switch{float:left;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the content into the label using css (::after) and using position relative to place it to the desired location.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 20px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slider::after {
  position:relative;
  right:-55px;

  content: "label"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I guess it should work.

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47px;
  height: 20px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```
<body>

  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <div class="slider round"></div>
    <span>LABEL 1</span>
  </label>

</body>
```