# Add "ON" / "OFF" text to togglebutton

Tags: javascript, html, css, togglebutton

I'm trying to add text to some togglebuttons; "ON" in the purple section when the button is on, and "OFF" in the grey section when the toggle is off. I've tried using the `content: "ON"` property to add "ON" or "OFF", but I may be using it incorrectly. Any help will be appreciated.

Link to js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hbybnbn/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221978/add-label-to-right-of-toggle-button) answer out. The CSS `::before` and `::after` can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looking at the ::before pseudoelement did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Created a `::before` pseudoelement and styles/positioned it as required.

```js
/*!
    
 =========================================================
 * Material Kit - v1.1.1.0
 =========================================================
 
 * Product Page: http://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-kit
 * Copyright 2017 Creative Tim (http://www.creative-tim.com)
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/timcreative/material-kit/blob/master/LICENSE.md)
 
 =========================================================
 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 
 */

var transparent = true;

var transparentDemo = true;
var fixedTop = false;

var navbar_initialized = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Init Material scripts for buttons ripples, inputs animations etc, more info on the next link https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design#materialjs
  $.material.init();

  //  Activate the Tooltips
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // Activate Datepicker
  if ($('.datepicker').length != 0) {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      weekStart: 1
    });
  }

  // Check if we have the class "navbar-color-on-scroll" then add the function to remove the class "navbar-transparent" so it will transform to a plain color.
  if ($('.navbar-color-on-scroll').length != 0) {
    $(window).on('scroll', materialKit.checkScrollForTransparentNavbar)
  }

  // Activate Popovers
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

  // Active Carousel
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 400000
  });

});

materialKit = {
  misc: {
    navbar_menu_visible: 0
  },

  checkScrollForTransparentNavbar: debounce(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 260) {
      if (transparent) {
        transparent = false;
        $('.navbar-color-on-scroll').removeClass('navbar-transparent');
      }
    } else {
      if (!transparent) {
        transparent = true;
        $('.navbar-color-on-scroll').addClass('navbar-transparent');
      }
    }
  }, 17),

  initSliders: function() {
    // Sliders for demo purpose
    $('#sliderRegular').noUiSlider({
      start: 40,
      connect: "lower",
      range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      }
    });

    $('#sliderDouble').noUiSlider({
      start: [20, 60],
      connect: true,
      range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      }
    });
  }
}


var big_image;

materialKitDemo = {
  checkScrollForParallax: debounce(function() {
    var current_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    oVal = ($(window).scrollTop() / 3);
    big_image.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(0,' + oVal + 'px,0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(0,' + oVal + 'px,0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(0,' + oVal + 'px,0)',
      '-o-transform': 'translate3d(0,' + oVal + 'px,0)'
    });

  }, 6)

}
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    }, wait);
    if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

! function(t) {
  function o(t) {
    return "undefined" == typeof t.which ? !0 : "number" == typeof t.which && t.which > 0 ? !t.ctrlKey && !t.metaKey && !t.altKey && 8 != t.which && 9 != t.which && 13 != t.which && 16 != t.which && 17 != t.which && 20 != t.which && 27 != t.which : !1
  }

  function i(o) {
    var i = t(o);
    i.prop("disabled") || i.closest(".form-group").addClass("is-focused")
  }

  function n(o) {
    o.closest("label").hover(function() {
      var o = t(this).find("input");
      o.prop("disabled") || i(o)
    }, function() {
      e(t(this).find("input"))
    })
  }

  function e(o) {
    t(o).closest(".form-group").removeClass("is-focused")
  }
  t.expr[":"].notmdproc = function(o) {
    return t(o).data("mdproc") ? !1 : !0
  }, t.material = {
    options: {
      validate: !0,
      input: !0,
      ripples: !0,
      checkbox: !0,
      togglebutton: !0,
      radio: !0,
      arrive: !0,
      autofill: !1,
      withRipples: [".btn:not(.btn-link)", ".card-image", ".navbar a:not(.withoutripple)", ".footer a:not(.withoutripple)", ".dropdown-menu a", ".nav-tabs a:not(.withoutripple)", ".withripple", ".pagination li:not(.active):not(.disabled) a:not(.withoutripple)"].join(","),
      inputElements: "input.form-control, textarea.form-control, select.form-control",
      checkboxElements: ".checkbox > label > input[type=checkbox]",
      togglebuttonElements: ".togglebutton > label > input[type=checkbox]",
      radioElements: ".radio > label > input[type=radio]"
    },
    checkbox: function(o) {
      var i = t(o ? o : this.options.checkboxElements).filter(":notmdproc").data("mdproc", !0).after("<span class='checkbox-material'><span class='check'></span></span>");
      n(i)
    },
    togglebutton: function(o) {
      var i = t(o ? o : this.options.togglebuttonElements).filter(":notmdproc").data("mdproc", !0).after("<span class='toggle'></span>");
      n(i)
    },
    radio: function(o) {
      var i = t(o ? o : this.options.radioElements).filter(":notmdproc").data("mdproc", !0).after("<span class='circle'></span><span class='check'></span>");
      n(i)
    },
    input: function(o) {
      t(o ? o : this.options.inputElements).filter(":notmdproc").data("mdproc", !0).each(function() {
        var o = t(this),
          i = o.closest(".form-group");
        0 === i.length && (o.wrap("<div class='form-group'></div>"), i = o.closest(".form-group")), o.attr("data-hint") && (o.after("<p class='help-block'>" + o.attr("data-hint") + "</p>"), o.removeAttr("data-hint"));
        var n = {
          "input-lg": "form-group-lg",
          "input-sm": "form-group-sm"
        };
        if (t.each(n, function(t, n) {
            o.hasClass(t) && (o.removeClass(t), i.addClass(n))
          }), o.hasClass("floating-label")) {
          var e = o.attr("placeholder");
          o.attr("placeholder", null).removeClass("floating-label");
          var a = o.attr("id"),
            r = "";
          a && (r = "for='" + a + "'"), i.addClass("label-floating"), o.after("<label " + r + "class='control-label'>" + e + "</label>")
        }(null === o.val() || "undefined" == o.val() || "" === o.val()) && i.addClass("is-empty"), i.append("<span class='material-input'></span>"), i.find("input[type=file]").length > 0 && i.addClass("is-fileinput")
      })
    },
    attachInputEventHandlers: function() {
      var n = this.options.validate;
      t(document).on("change", ".checkbox input[type=checkbox]", function() {
        t(this).blur()
      }).on("keydown paste", ".form-control", function(i) {
        o(i) && t(this).closest(".form-group").removeClass("is-empty")
      }).on("keyup change", ".form-control", function() {
        var o = t(this),
          i = o.closest(".form-group"),
          e = "undefined" == typeof o[0].checkValidity || o[0].checkValidity();
        "" === o.val() ? i.addClass("is-empty") : i.removeClass("is-empty"), n && (e ? i.removeClass("has-error") : i.addClass("has-error"))
      }).on("focus", ".form-control, .form-group.is-fileinput", function() {
        i(this)
      }).on("blur", ".form-control, .form-group.is-fileinput", function() {
        e(this)
      }).on("change", ".form-group input", function() {
        var o = t(this);
        if ("file" != o.attr("type")) {
          var i = o.closest(".form-group"),
            n = o.val();
          n ? i.removeClass("is-empty") : i.addClass("is-empty")
        }
      }).on("change", ".form-group.is-fileinput input[type='file']", function() {
        var o = t(this),
          i = o.closest(".form-group"),
          n = "";
        t.each(this.files, function(t, o) {
          n += o.name + ", "
        }), n = n.substring(0, n.length - 2), n ? i.removeClass("is-empty") : i.addClass("is-empty"), i.find("input.form-control[readonly]").val(n)
      })
    },
    ripples: function(o) {
      t(o ? o : this.options.withRipples).ripples()
    },
    autofill: function() {
      var o = setInterval(function() {
        t("input[type!=checkbox]").each(function() {
          var o = t(this);
          o.val() && o.val() !== o.attr("value") && o.trigger("change")
        })
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(o)
      }, 1e4)
    },
    attachAutofillEventHandlers: function() {
      var o;
      t(document).on("focus", "input", function() {
        var i = t(this).parents("form").find("input").not("[type=file]");
        o = setInterval(function() {
          i.each(function() {
            var o = t(this);
            o.val() !== o.attr("value") && o.trigger("change")
          })
        }, 100)
      }).on("blur", ".form-group input", function() {
        clearInterval(o)
      })
    },
    init: function(o) {
      this.options = t.extend({}, this.options, o);
      var i = t(document);
      t.fn.ripples && this.options.ripples && this.ripples(), this.options.input && (this.input(), this.attachInputEventHandlers()), this.options.checkbox && this.checkbox(), this.options.togglebutton && this.togglebutton(), this.options.radio && this.radio(), this.options.autofill && (this.autofill(), this.attachAutofillEventHandlers()), document.arrive && this.options.arrive && (t.fn.ripples && this.options.ripples && i.arrive(this.options.withRipples, function() {
        t.material.ripples(t(this))
      }), this.options.input && i.arrive(this.options.inputElements, function() {
        t.material.input(t(this))
      }), this.options.checkbox && i.arrive(this.options.checkboxElements, function() {
        t.material.checkbox(t(this))
      }), this.options.radio && i.arrive(this.options.radioElements, function() {
        t.material.radio(t(this))
      }), this.options.togglebutton && i.arrive(this.options.togglebuttonElements, function() {
        t.material.togglebutton(t(this))
      }))
    }
  }
}(jQuery),
function(t, o, i, n) {
  "use strict";

  function e(o, i) {
    r = this, this.element = t(o), this.options = t.extend({}, s, i), this._defaults = s, this._name = a, this.init()
  }
  var a = "ripples",
    r = null,
    s = {};
  e.prototype.init = function() {
    var i = this.element;
    i.on("mousedown touchstart", function(n) {
      if (!r.isTouch() || "mousedown" !== n.type) {
        i.find(".ripple-container").length || i.append('<div class="ripple-container"></div>');
        var e = i.children(".ripple-container"),
          a = r.getRelY(e, n),
          s = r.getRelX(e, n);
        if (a || s) {
          var l = r.getRipplesColor(i),
            p = t("<div></div>");
          p.addClass("ripple").css({
              left: s,
              top: a,
              "background-color": l
            }), e.append(p),
            function() {
              return o.getComputedStyle(p[0]).opacity
            }(), r.rippleOn(i, p), setTimeout(function() {
              r.rippleEnd(p)
            }, 500), i.on("mouseup mouseleave touchend", function() {
              p.data("mousedown", "off"), "off" === p.data("animating") && r.rippleOut(p)
            })
        }
      }
    })
  }, e.prototype.getNewSize = function(t, o) {
    return Math.max(t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()) / o.outerWidth() * 2.5
  }, e.prototype.getRelX = function(t, o) {
    var i = t.offset();
    return r.isTouch() ? (o = o.originalEvent, 1 === o.touches.length ? o.touches[0].pageX - i.left : !1) : o.pageX - i.left
  }, e.prototype.getRelY = function(t, o) {
    var i = t.offset();
    return r.isTouch() ? (o = o.originalEvent, 1 === o.touches.length ? o.touches[0].pageY - i.top : !1) : o.pageY - i.top
  }, e.prototype.getRipplesColor = function(t) {
    var i = t.data("ripple-color") ? t.data("ripple-color") : o.getComputedStyle(t[0]).color;
    return i
  }, e.prototype.hasTransitionSupport = function() {
    var t = i.body || i.documentElement,
      o = t.style,
      e = o.transition !== n || o.WebkitTransition !== n || o.MozTransition !== n || o.MsTransition !== n || o.OTransition !== n;
    return e
  }, e.prototype.isTouch = function() {
    return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
  }, e.prototype.rippleEnd = function(t) {
    t.data("animating", "off"), "off" === t.data("mousedown") && r.rippleOut(t)
  }, e.prototype.rippleOut = function(t) {
    t.off(), r.hasTransitionSupport() ? t.addClass("ripple-out") : t.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 100, function() {
      t.trigger("transitionend")
    }), t.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
      t.remove()
    })
  }, e.prototype.rippleOn = function(t, o) {
    var i = r.getNewSize(t, o);
    r.hasTransitionSupport() ? o.css({
      "-ms-transform": "scale(" + i + ")",
      "-moz-transform": "scale(" + i + ")",
      "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + i + ")",
      transform: "scale(" + i + ")"
    }).addClass("ripple-on").data("animating", "on").data("mousedown", "on") : o.animate({
      width: 2 * Math.max(t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()),
      height: 2 * Math.max(t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()),
      "margin-left": -1 * Math.max(t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()),
      "margin-top": -1 * Math.max(t.outerWidth(), t.outerHeight()),
      opacity: .2
    }, 500, function() {
      o.trigger("transitionend")
    })
  }, t.fn.ripples = function(o) {
    return this.each(function() {
      t.data(this, "plugin_" + a) || t.data(this, "plugin_" + a, new e(this, o))
    })
  }
}(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.togglebutton {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.togglebutton,
.togglebutton label,
.togglebutton input,
.togglebutton .toggle {
  user-select: none;
}

.togglebutton label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.form-group.is-focused .togglebutton label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.form-group.is-focused .togglebutton label:hover,
.form-group.is-focused .togglebutton label:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);
}

fieldset[disabled] .form-group.is-focused .togglebutton label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.togglebutton label .toggle {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.togglebutton label .toggle,
.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox][disabled]+.toggle {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #aeb0b5;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.togglebutton label .toggle:before {
  content: "OFF";
  position: relative;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 9px;
  left: 14px;
  top: -4.5px
}

.togglebutton label .toggle:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: -7px;
  top: -23px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.1s ease;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox][disabled]+.toggle:after,
.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox][disabled]:checked+.toggle:after {
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]+.toggle:active:after,
.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox][disabled]+.toggle:active:after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle:after {
  left: 8px;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle {
  background-color: #9bdaf1;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle:before {
  content: "ON";
  color: #4a4a4a;
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
  left: 3px
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle:after {
  top: -3px;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle:after {
  border-color: #00a6d2;
  background-color: #00a6d2;
}

.togglebutton label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.toggle:active:after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 15px rgba(0, 166, 210, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- you can use the class main-raised if you want the main area to be as a page with shadows -->
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">

        <!-- here you can add your content -->
        <div class="togglebutton">
          <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="">
      Toggle is on
     </label>
        </div>

        <div class="togglebutton">
          <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Toggle is off
     </label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```